# document style for paper editing

Tags: typography

Many of the LaTeX styles (e.g., article, memoir, and koma-script) seem designed to produce beautiful documents that are easy to read. Is there a document class (or options) or typographical rules that creates hard copy documents are are easy to edit (yes, I still like to edit hard copies)? In someways, I think that easy to read hinders editing where I am trying to force myself to read word-by-word. Wide spaces between lines might be ugly, but it makes it easier to insert comments.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the spacing, for example with the `setspace` package?

Comment: @AndrewUzzell if I knew what the typographical rules are, I am guessing implementing them will be rather straight forward (especially with the help of tx.sx).

Comment: I'd simply increase line spacing (as suggested), decrease the margins (better would be to use two columns, but this might not be easily done for all documents).  If you want to make it somewhat less pleasant to read, you could use `\raggedright` (or the `ragged2e` package).  At the same time, I don't think there are any 'typographical rules' for how to make (as it were) bad copy.  It seems counter-intuitive that anyone would create rules for what is, by definition, only a work in progress. Also: keep in mind that you need to be able to undo these changes fairly easily for the finished product.

Comment: Perhaps you could look at one of the questions about producing a Word-like document? We really need to know what you are looking for before anyone can answer you. Some people will prefer more line spacing, others will go for big margins, someone may even want to reproduce an old typewriter style, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A number of journal class files have a draft or preprint option, e.g.

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4}
```